# OCR parsing using tesseract parsing wrong text from image

Tags: php, tesseract

OCR Parsing using tesseract not returning proper data. I installed tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz using the link below:

http://miphol.com/muse/2013/05/install-tesseract-ocr-on-ubunt.html

tesseract is installed properly and I tested the same using command line.

```
/usr/local/bin/tesseract /var/www/html/xxx/test/test.jpg /var/www/html/xxx/test/output1 -l eng

or

/usr/local/bin/tesseract /var/www/html/xxx/test/test.jpg /var/www/html/xxx/test/output1
```

But it is showing the result like :

```
-M

NATURAL WORKS
LOMFANV

mvmc: nu amer number: anon

Kev one Detils

uduln mm
u-dun-5: Nm1n,1mn
sin‘-.nm..u 34Wnt1¢IuD-EYSDANHY
nuﬁ-.n..u.u
my-=um.=—zu.uum
u.u-u.._.n £1149
Iuynunnntni smawxmwawan



ram lhn: Bnan
xmams

am: manam-grmsusqn m m
Ana. mg 1 Sn lmgﬁdd avail:

ua._ we 2

any Enrllllh-Em

um Anaaamm
v-an an: 514 mu
Ia-my mm m-gum. (Great Enlam)

khan-. nmmsum

nu.-no) Axum:

Bnan nmaws
Sn lulﬁdd swung

um-r-gt-am
Amagmm

314 mu

umai w:-gown (Gas! Enlam)

unum Works unmullli
vo Em 1rm1

Eurllllh-Em

wst Mdards

m mx

urn.

Ema .m@...auua».nasm-ruamm .a
wax»; www mmanwmmaruamm m

mam

Sm lad:-euun:

Q-mivluine n.._.n

ham
:1:
224

Mntrahs muss-m Mn: Vua Babylmm

1 mm mm

m..«y-.:ay-u-name

Bﬂmal: us:
umanasnn: mm
nmnuumsnn mm
um-.musnman: us:
9-pp-v-;a..m..iu-1 an
nhl nus
```

For the image :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zwoF.jpg)

I will use shell_exec(PHP) to read text and working in linux platform. Please suggest where I am making mistake.

Comment: OCR parsing is never an exact science. There is no way you will 100% get the text you want. Too many things can affect the accuracy, like fonts, resolution, spacing, etc. Only advice I can give you is that you should probably treat your image before passing it through tesseract. Generally dropping saturation to 0 and upping contrast will probably get you better results. You can also train it for specific fonts to bring up accuracy.

Comment: I have done the same thing using abbyy and it works fine, but it is a paid api. Can you please suggest some other tool to do OCR parsing for free with good accuracy level..

Comment: Tesseract is the best open source OCR software out there. It can be pretty accurate with proper image treatment and training. However, nothing will beat the paid solutions out there.